# Accessing remote (Invoke-Command) array variable in local session

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to access the array variable outside the invoke command. I tried the below code, where I cannot access the remote array variable from my local session.

```
$serverlist = @("server1", "server2")

foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
    #Write-Host $computer

    $vinodh = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        $testVar = @("Stack", "over", "flow")
    }
}
foreach ($vars in $testVar) {
    Write-Host $vars # Unable to get the values as stack,over, flow
}
```

Actual results: unable to get values.

I expect the output as

```
stack
over
flow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables set inside the remote session were not populated to the local powershell session ([About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6)). You could `return` the values from the invoked session for using later.

```
$ReturnValues = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
    $testVar=@("Stack","over","flow")
    return  $testVar #return data
}

foreach ($ReturnValue in $ReturnValues)
{
    $ReturnValue
}
```

Comment: Note that using the `return` keyword is not required. PowerShell by default returns all non-captured regular output.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can we return multiple array variable ?

Comment: Can we return multiple array variable and then i need to iterate each of them using for loop